# repeat rows based on column python

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Input]

There are some missing row are in column Customer and Site. Code is able to replicate same value to the missing cell till the other col have.

Like in my example Customer and site has 5 entries and other column has 15 entries, So code is able to fill other missing value on col Customer and Site with respect to col 'a' .Attached output for reference.

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame()
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.a))
```

Output Look like this in Red Colour.

[image: Output]

Comment: Please add a reproducable data frame as text to your question. For example using df.to_dict()

Comment: Code is able to repeat Customer and Sites based on the a,b,c,d,e column. As in the given example, only column 'a' is complete row so consider 'a' to fill 'Customer' and 'Site'

Comment: the question is not clear. what are you trying to achieve ?  please edit the original question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I included some edge cases, cause not sure what exactly you want:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer': ['Sony', 'Samsung', 'Nokia'] + [None]*2 + [None]*4 + ['LG', 'Ford'] + [None]*3,
    'site': ['s1', 's2', 's3'] + [None]*2 + [None]*4 + ['s4', 's5'] + [None]*3,
    'a': ['xy']*3 + ['abc']*2 + ['xyw']*4 + ['rty']*2 + ['zxc']*3,
})
   Customer  site    a
0      Sony    s1   xy
1   Samsung    s2   xy
2     Nokia    s3   xy
3      None  None  abc
4      None  None  abc
5      None  None  xyw
6      None  None  xyw
7      None  None  xyw
8      None  None  xyw
9        LG    s4  rty
10     Ford    s5  rty
11     None  None  zxc
12     None  None  zxc
13     None  None  zxc
```

My approach is to index your dataframe by group (`a` column in your example) and row_number within each group. Then you can get values to fill by selecting with indexes.

First, let's add some helper columns and add index:

```py
import numpy as np
df['rn'] = df.groupby('a').cumcount()+1
df['a_filled'] = pd.Series(np.where(df.Customer.isnull(), None, df.a)).fillna(method='ffill')
df2 = df.set_index(['a','rn'], drop=False)
```

`a_filled` shows from which group to take values to fill missing rows.

And now for each missing row we can refer to the correct value to fill:

```py
fill_cols = ['Customer', 'site']
cond = lambda x: x.Customer.isnull()
df2.loc[cond, fill_cols] = df2.loc[cond].apply(lambda x: df2.loc[(x.a_filled, x.rn), fill_cols] if (x.a_filled, x.rn) in df2.index else None, axis=1)

       Customer  site    a  rn a_filled
a   rn
xy  1      Sony    s1   xy   1       xy
    2   Samsung    s2   xy   2       xy
    3     Nokia    s3   xy   3       xy
abc 1      Sony    s1  abc   1       xy
    2   Samsung    s2  abc   2       xy
xyw 1      Sony    s1  xyw   1       xy
    2   Samsung    s2  xyw   2       xy
    3     Nokia    s3  xyw   3       xy
    4      None  None  xyw   4       xy
rty 1        LG    s4  rty   1      rty
    2      Ford    s5  rty   2      rty
zxc 1        LG    s4  zxc   1      rty
    2      Ford    s5  zxc   2      rty
    3      None  None  zxc   3      rty
```

`if (x.a_filled, x.rn) in df2.index` is added to avoid KeyError - when we try to fill bigger group with values from smaller group.

Comment: Output Looks Like : Values of 'Customer' and 'Site' will replicate till the last value of col a. shown in red color. All the company names and sites replicates 3 times in this case because col a has 15 rows.

Comment: @deeplearning, well yes, it's just like you describe. Have you actually tried to run the code, for your input data?

Comment: In col 'Customer' and 'Site', there should not be any NaN. All values need to replicate based on the col a.

Comment: @deeplearning, yeah, whatever